# Develop webcam chat application

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, video-streaming

I am trying build small webcam chat (web application). I searched on google and found some solutions but I don't think the documents and blogs suggested meet my needs.

I am looking for complete open source stack with Apache/MIT like license.

I don't want to use flex/flash based code.

Could you recommend:
  - a good server 
  - Is it possible without flash/flex? If yes then how? I mean any specific Javascript lib for the same. 
  - I would appriciate some pointers are provided with some kind application architecture.

It includes both client and server. I know there are some Servers hosting is available but i don't want to go for that.

Comment: use google maybe?!? i typed in free `non flash chat programs for php` and found some results. http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/chat-scripts/      |   Pro Chat Rooms, Aerochat... those are just a couple i found.

Comment: You cannot use webcam in your web applications (at least portable ones) without Flash, Java, Silverlight, ActiveX or similar technologies.

Comment: you can't do it without flash. actionscript code for taking webcam stream and sending it to server via sockets should be simple enough. then you could create javascript wrapper on top, to control flash. check how this works: http://kawanet.blogspot.com/2009/05/jsartoolkit-ar-augmented-reality-by.html

Comment: @spacevillain - Yes this blog is help me to understand to reduce flex/flash code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost 100% sure there isn't a built in library for that with js or is it possible to make your own library. you have to have some kind of browser plugin. flash might be the best way to go considering that almost everyone has it. If you really can't use flash try using java. if you can't do that, look for a browser plugin and then instruct clients to install it. if you can't do that then your probably out of options. if this isn't helpful, tell us why you can't use flash.

Comment: Another thing to consider might be having java and flash. that if they don't have one, it can use the other.

Comment: As a non-Flash user (Flashblock) I can say that many non-Flash users know, expect, and actually prefer "reduced functionality". Therefore I would _not_ expect webcam support from a webpage on my system. Of course, this comment only applies to us users who deliberately avoid Flash, not to users for whom Flash is not available.